# Explanation of Perl's syntax from module MoreUtils.pm

Tags: perl

I am seeking explanation of the syntax of Perl's uniq and fidrstidx function from module MoreUtils.pm.

Having sought that, I already know other ways to get uniq array elements from an array having duplicate elements and finding the first index from an array by below ways :

```
## remove duplicate elements ##

my @arr = qw (2 4 2 8 3 4 6);
my @uniq = ();
my %hash = ();
@uniq = grep {!$hash{$_}++ } @arr;

### first index ###

@arr = qw (Java ooperl Ruby cgiperl Python);
my ($index) = grep {$arr[$_] =~ /perl/} 0..$#arr;
```

Can anybody please explain me second line of this below sub uniq function comprising map and ternary operator from MoreUtils.pm:

```
 map {$h{$_}++ == 0 ? $_ : () } @;
```

and also

the &@ passed to firstidx function and the below line in the body of the function :

```
 local *_ = \$_[$i];
```

What I understand that sub routine ref is passed to firstidx. But a bit more detailed explanation will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to limit yourself to a single question at a time. What don't you understand? Do you need the post increment operator explaining to you? The comparison operator? Ternary operations? Maps? Hashes? Arrays? Sigils?

Comment: `map` returning empty list `()` filters elements (can be used instead of `grep`)

Comment: @Quentin Well, I know what a post increment operator, ternary, maps and hashes do. Basically it is checking if $h{$_} is equaled to zero then returning $_ and after that incrementing its value by 1  else empty list. However was a bt confused with the syntax as it seemed a bit cryptic, so I asked.

Comment: `local *_` should localize `_` globtype filehandle (just like `local *FH` does) but it also [changes value](https://metacpan.org/source/VPARSEVAL/List-MoreUtils-0.17/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm#L87) of `$_`. Additional question would be why not using `local $_ = ..`

Comment: @Сухой27 `local *_ = \$value` creates an *alias* to the given value, not a copy like `local $_ = $value`. So it's more like `for ($value) { … }`

Comment: @amon tnx, good to see you back on SO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your second question was answered in the comments.

Your first question asks about `map {$h{$_}++ == 0 ? $_ : () } @;` from [List::MoreUtils](http://www.metacpan.org/module/List::MoreUtils). In recent versions, it's actually in `List::MoreUtils::PP` (for Pure Perl) since many of the subroutines are also implemented in C and XS. Here's the current version of the Pure Perl `uniq`:

```
sub uniq (@)
{
    my %seen = ();
    my $k;
    my $seen_undef;
    grep { defined $_ ? not $seen{ $k = $_ }++ : not $seen_undef++ } @_;
}
```

This has the same `map` technique although it's using `grep` instead. The `grep` goes through all of the elements in `@_` and has to return either true or false for each of them. The elements which evaluate to true end up in the output list. The code then wants to make an element evaluate to true the first time it sees it and false the rest of the times.

In this code it handles `undef` separately. If the current element is not undef, it does the first branch of the conditional operator and the second branch otherwise. Now let's look at the branches.

The defined case adds an element to a hash. No one left code comments about the use of `$k` but it probably has something to do with not disturbing `$_`. That `$k` becomes the key for the hash:

```
 not $seen{ $k = $_ }++
```

If that is the first time that key has been encountered the value of the hash is undef. That post-increment does its work *after* the value is used so hold off on thinking about that for a moment. The low-precendence `not` sees the value of `$seen{$k}`, which is `undef`. The `not` turns the false value of `undef` into true. That true indicates that the `grep` has seen `$_` for the first time. It becomes part of the output list. Then the `++` does its work and increments the `undef` value to `1`. On all subsequent encounters with the same value the hash value will be true. The `not` will turn the true value into false and that element won't be in the output list.

The `map` you show implements the `grep`. It returns an element when the condition is true and returns no elements when it is false:

```
map {$h{$_}++ == 0 ? $_ : () } @_;
```

For each element it adds it as the key in the hash and compares the value to 0. The first time an element is seen that value is `undef`. In numeric context an `undef` is `0`. So, the `==` returns true and the first branch of the conditional operator fires, returning `$_` to the output list. The `++` then increments the hash value from `undef` to `1`. The next time it encounters the same value the hash value is not `0` and the second branch of the conditional operator returns the empty list. That adds no elements to the output list.

Comment: This is exactly the explanation I was looking for. So wonderfully elaborated by breaking it into small pieces. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4):

Newer version of `List::MoreUtils` [don't use the construct any more](https://metacpan.org/source/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.423/lib/List/MoreUtils/PP.pm#L524), but as Сухой27 explained,

```
map { CONDITION ? $_ : () } LIST
```

is just a fancy alternative to

```
grep { CONDITION } LIST
```

I don't think there's any overarching reason the author chose `map` for this implementation, and in fact it was simplified to `grep` in later versions of `List::MoreUtils`.

The `firstidx` syntax is `firstidx BLOCK LIST`. Like the builtin `map` and `grep`, it is specified that the code in `BLOCK` will operate on the variable `$_`, and *that the code is allowed to make changes to* `$_`. So in the `firstidx` implementation, it is not sufficient to set `$_` to each value in `LIST`. Rather, `$_` must be aliased to each element of `LIST` so that a change in `$_` inside `BLOCK` also results to a change in the element in the `LIST`. This is accomplished by manipulating the symbol table

```
local *_ = \$scalar         # make $_ an alias of $scalar
```

And you use `local` so that when `firstidx` is done, we haven't clobbered any useful information that was previously in the `$_` variable.

Comment: Wonderful explanation. Thanks a lot.